# arrange following number

Tags: java

Output
2 4 5 8 16 17 32 64 127 128 129

with Java+for

i try to..

```
    int num=2;
    for(int n=1;n<=11;n++){

        if(n%3==0 || n%10==0){
            num+=1;

            System.out.println(num);

        }else{

        num=n*2;

        System.out.println(num);

        }
    }

}
```

but fail.. can anyone advice me plz

Comment: What is the actual assignment? The way you stated it, one solution is `System.out.println("2 4 5 8 16 17 32 64 127 128 129");`

Comment: Are you sure about the last three values? `65, 128, 256` instead of the given numbers would create an easier sequence...

Comment: @darioo - `Java+for` is a requirement!

Comment: @Andreas_D - but what does "arrange" mean in this context?

Comment: Perhaps it's just a sequence of ifs inside the for ...

Comment: @Andreas_D: I stand corrected. `int[] a = {2, 4, 5, 8, 16, 17, 32, 64, 127, 128, 129};  for (int i : a)  System.out.println(i);` is another solution, but this isn't what OP wants...

Comment: @darioo I start to think it is

Comment: It seems like the last number should be 256 instead of 129.

Comment: sorry for my poor english.. maybe my question is wrong.. thank you all : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int num = 1;
for (int n = 1; n < 12; n++) {
    if (n > 8) {
        System.out.println(n + 118);
    } else if (n % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.println(num + 1);
    } else {
        num *= 2;
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```